# Catch all outgoing email in mercury

Tags: email, xampp

I have installed XAMPP 3 on Windows XP, and I am trying to configure Mercury to catch all outgoing email on my development machine.

This is for the purpose of testing the email feature after registering a locally developed web application.

Any ideas?

Comment: please fix grammar, provide links to the software you are using (mercury), name the OS etc. assume for a moment you should answer your answer: what information would you need to do it?

Answer (score 3):

After having the same question (well, at least in the idea) i found the solution to catch all mail using mercury:

1. Make sure you permit relaying of non-local mail: [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gzl9jrb8uxbxsrp/Mercury_32_2013-12-03_15-29-53.png)
2. Create a user for catching all the emails (note: it can be any name, not necessarily 'archive'): [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cw8iteta3na0m5p/Mercury_32_2013-12-03_15-32-15.png)
3. Create a new user in 'MercuryD POP3 Client'. use the same username as you did in (2): [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/izilsbentk141yh/Mercury_32_2013-12-03_15-35-22.png)
4. in Configuration>Filtering rules>Edit global rules... create two new 'Always triggers' rules in the **following order**: [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lafvf3q8jhykl2c/Mercury_32_2013-12-03_15-38-46.png)

Note that 'forward message' rule should have parameter set as the email of the user you created on (2): [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8cnwz3s07adom05/Edit%20filtering%20rule%20set_2013-12-03_15-39-37.png)

Now set up your favorite email client with the catch-all user you just created, and you're all set.